# Past perfect and reference time

Tags: past-perfect

I don't really understand why we use past perfect here:

**It had been earlier reported that four people were taken to the hospital.**

The pre-history has been written in past simple, and it has stated that two people were taken into the hospital. If reference time is the moment when people were taken to the hospital, then how can we use past perfect in the beginning? The reporting of this moment ocurred after this event took place...

Comment: We actually need another event, another sentence of context, to determine whether this is called for here. There is no second verb too compare reference points.

Comment: The reporting happened _after_ the people were taken to hospital, but presumably _before_ some other event that is being referred to.

Comment: I understand that the reporting happened after the people were taken to hospital. But in that case, people were taken to the hopsital also before some other event that is being referred to. Then why do not we use past perfect for it as well? Both these events happened before this event